# RX-java2 repeat consumption of an Observable

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have 3 Observables, the output of the first observable is required by the second observable. And the output the both first and second observable is required by the third observable.

```
    Observable<String> observableOne = Observable
        .just("{1}")
        .map(v -> {
            System.out.println("Executing Observable 1");
            return v;
        });

    Observable<String> observableTwo = observableOne
        .map(observableOneValue -> {
            System.out.println("Executing Observable 2");
            return "{2"+observableOneValue+"}";
        });

    Observable.zip(
        observableOne,
        observableTwo,
        (observableOneValue, observableTwoValue) ->
        {
            System.out.println("Executing Observable 3");
            return "{3"+observableOneValue+observableTwoValue+"}";
        }
    ).blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```

This repeats the execution of the first observable, I can certainly make the first observable cacheable. But I was wondering if there is a better option than that, particularly I am looking for some kind of message passing construct from the first to the other two observables

Comment: See the relevant section in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for by a "message passing construct".  `cache` will work for you example above, but you mention you don't want to use that.

Another option that might fit your use case is using [`ConnectableObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators). It only starts emitting items when you call `connect` on it, not when it is subscribed to.  Convert your `observableOne` to a `ConnectableObservable` by calling `publish`.  Then set up all your subscribers.  Then call `connect` on `observableOne`.

```
ConnectableObservable<String> observableOne = Observable
        .just("{1}")
        .map(v -> {
          System.out.println("Executing Observable 1");
          return v;
        }).publish();

    Observable<String> observableTwo = observableOne
        .map(observableOneValue -> {
          System.out.println("Executing Observable 2");
          return "{2"+observableOneValue+"}";
        });

    Observable.zip(
        observableOne,
        observableTwo,
        (observableOneValue, observableTwoValue) ->
        {
          System.out.println("Executing Observable 3");
          return "{3"+observableOneValue+observableTwoValue+"}";
        }
    ).subscribe(System.out::println);

    // Call when all the subscribers are ready --
    observableOne.connect();
```

Notes

- `observableOne` is now a `ConnectableObservable`
- need to use `subscribe` instead of `blockingSubscribe` so the code will execute the `connect` call.